# Node child_process "submit" stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, stdin, read-eval-print-loop

My problem is as follows: I want to write to stdin multiple times and get output from stdout after "submiting" stdin. So far i tryed

```
stdin.cork()
stdin.uncork()
```

but only `stdin.end()` seams to work.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

const node = spawn('node')

node.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(`${data}`))

node.stdin.write(`console.log('hello, world!')\n`) 
// here I want stdin to actualy write to process
node.stdin.end()
```

Eventually I want to build abstraction around this, and I nead to keep process alive.

Also I don't want to use node as process but other repls that's why im stuck to stdio

Comment: `node.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(`${data}`))` this is recursive just saying ...

Comment: How? those are diffrent processes